# Stop Visual Studio 2019 from complaining about field prefixes

Tags: visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

I have .editorconfig set up in a solution, stating among other things that private fields should be camelCase:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.private_lowercase.symbols                             = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_lowercase.style                               = camel_case
dotnet_naming_rule.private_lowercase.severity                            = suggestion
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds                    = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities          = private
```

After upgrading from VS 2017 to 2019, it started complaining about certain private fields that have an underscore prefix (like `_exampleOne`). It says: `Naming rule violation: Prefix '_' is not expected`.

I use underscores to signify "technicality" fields: the ones which are closely tied to specific properties or methods and shouldn't be manipulated directly. For instance, when a manual property implementation is required for event raising or other purposes.

Can I make Visual Studio stop complaining about those specific problems without turning off IDE1006 completely or suppressing it on a per-use basis? Those are the only solutions the little yellow light bulb suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is being worked on by Microsoft currently.  The change is currently "In Review" as of 05/18/2021.  You can follow the issue on GitHub at: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47569
Until this is fixed you have several options:

1. Suppress the issue around each time it occurs using disable and optional "restore" right afterwards:
   `#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles private int _myPrivateVariable; #pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles`
2. Suppress in a Suppression File
3. Suppress in Source using:
   `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles", Justification = "<Pending>")]`
4. Configure Severity to an acceptable level:
   None, Silent, Suggestion, Warning, Error

Looks like Microsoft agrees this is an issue that should be resolved and hopefully soon.